# How can I convert a data frame into 3-D matrix with the values of two columns of data frame forming column headings of the matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have following dataframe

`A B  C C
a 1 ca da
b 2 cb db
c 3 cc dc`

I want to convert above to the form .
[,,1]

  `a   b   c
1 ca  0   0
2 0   cb  0
3 0   0   cc`

[,,2]

  `a   b   c
1 da  0   0
2 0   db  0
3 0   0   dc`

Comment: not sure this is exactly what you want (its not 3D)  but ... `reshape2::dcast(data=dat, B ~ A, value.var="C", fill=0)`

Comment: @user20650 Can you give one more look

Comment: I'm not sure. I must admit, the fact you are using matrices/arrays to mix characters and zeros makes this a wee bit weird ;)

Comment: okay, here is a monster! `simplify2array(lapply(c("C", "D"), function(i) reshape2::acast(data=dat, B ~ A ,  value.var=i, fill=0)))`

Comment: or `reshape2::acast(data=melt(dat, id.vars = 1:2), B ~ A ~variable, value.var="value", fill=0)`

Comment: @user20650 Wow! It works. Thanks! Now, time for me to understand how it works